# LWC Component visible depends on login user language

Tags: apex, translation, language, data-category

I have a LWC component which get the results from apex class. Now when I login as a Italy user with locale Italian (Italy)   and Language Italian, the component is not working. When i change Language to English it work fine. In apex class we don't have any language condition for display. To fix the issue I tried the same to replicate in a dev org but not able to replicate the same issue. When i change the language the component visibility is not getting affected. But when i change language in UAT it affects the visibility of the component. Do anyone know is there any other setting which need to be done to replicate the issue in a dev org.

APEX

```
public class cc_caseHandlingInstruction {
@auraenabled
public static knowledgeArticleData fetchKnowledgeWithCaseHandlingInstructions(string category){
    knowledgeArticleData data = new knowledgeArticleData();
    data.status = 'ERROR';
    data.articleDetails = null;
    list<user> userDataList = [SELECT Id,CC_CaseRole__c FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
    string serviceLevel = '';
    for(User u:userDataList){
        serviceLevel = u.CC_CaseRole__c ; 
    }
    system.debug(serviceLevel);
    string serviceLevelApiName = cc_caseHandlingInstruction.fetchCategoryApiName('Service_Level' , serviceLevel);
    if(!(serviceLevelApiName == 'ERROR' || serviceLevel == '')){
        try{
            Id knowledgeCaseHandlingRecordTypeId ;
            for (RecordType rc : [Select Id From RecordType where sobjecttype = 'Knowledge__kav' AND name = 'Case_Handling_Instruction' LIMIT 1]) {
                knowledgeCaseHandlingRecordTypeId =  rc.Id;
            }
            
            string query = 'SELECT id, Title, Category_Information_CaseHandlingInstr19__c,Category_Information_CategoryId__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Category_Information_CategoryId__c =:';
            query   += 'category AND recordtypeid =: knowledgeCaseHandlingRecordTypeId   WITH DATA CATEGORY  Service_Level__c AT '+ serviceLevelApiName +'__c  LIMIT 1' ;
            
            
            List<Knowledge__kav> knowledgeArticleList = Database.query(query);
            
            if(knowledgeArticleList.size()>0){
                for(Knowledge__kav kav : knowledgeArticleList){
                    data.status = 'SUCCESS';  
                    data.articleDetails = kav;
                }
            }else{
                data.status = 'ERROR';  
                data.articleDetails = null;  
                data.errorMessage = 'No Articles Found';
            }
        }Catch(exception e){
            data.errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
    }else{
        if(serviceLevel == ''||serviceLevel == 'none'||serviceLevel == null){
            data.errorMessage = 'User Case Role Not Populated';
        }else if(serviceLevelApiName == ''){
            data.errorMessage = 'User Case Role Configuration ERROR';
        }          
    }

    return data;
}

public static string fetchCategoryApiName(string categoryGroupName ,string CategoryLabel){
    try{
        List<String> objType = new List<String>();
        List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult> describeCategoryStructureResult;
        objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        
        
        List<DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair> pairsList = new List<DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair>();
        DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair pair = new DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair();
        pair.setSobject('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        pair.setDataCategoryGroupName(categoryGroupName);
        pairsList.add(pair);
        
        describeCategoryStructureResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures(pairsList, false);
        
        List<DataCategory> allCategories;
        
        for(DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult singleResult : describeCategoryStructureResult){
            
            DataCategory [] toplevelCategories = singleResult.getTopCategories();
            allCategories = getAllCategories(toplevelCategories);
            
            
        }
        for(DataCategory category : allCategories) {
            if(category.getLabel() == CategoryLabel){
                return category.getName();
                
            }
        }
        return 'ERROR';
    }catch(exception e){
        return 'ERROR';   
    }
}


private static DataCategory[] getAllCategories(DataCategory [] categories){
    if(categories.isEmpty()){
        return new DataCategory[]{};
            } else {
                DataCategory [] categoriesClone = categories.clone();
                DataCategory category = categoriesClone[0];
                DataCategory[] allCategories = new DataCategory[]{category};
                categoriesClone.remove(0);
                categoriesClone.addAll(category.getChildCategories());
                allCategories.addAll(getAllCategories(categoriesClone));
                return allCategories;
            }
}

public class knowledgeArticleData {
    @AuraEnabled public string status ;
    @AuraEnabled public string errorMessage; 
    @AuraEnabled public Knowledge__kav articleDetails;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find anything while debugging the issue in chrome dev tools and salesforce debug logs?

Comment: @maniaccoder Yes in system.debug(serviceLevel); the result is null when language is changed.

Comment: You mention the component is not visible - are you certain you understand why it's not visible? Is it because no data is returned from your apex controller, is it some visibility condition you have on the page, etc. You said `System.debug(serviceLevel)` is null - does the user record actually have a value and does your component receive the error message `User Case Role Not Populated`?

Comment: Did you check your debug logs? P.S. It's not normal to return 'ERROR' or something when a method fails. You should throw an [AuraHandledException](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html) so you can see the error the server is throwing.

Comment: Sorry the System.debug(serviceLevel) is getting value but serviceLevelApiName is getting null value. The user have case role assigned. As I said when i change the language it is not working. In browser console i am getting error undefined.

Comment: @SarojBera The LanguageLocaleKey is same for both the users.

Comment: Adding a debug statement in your for loop where you check `if(category.getLabel() == CategoryLabel)` would help understand if it pulled all the data category group structures to see if that's the issue or not. Are the profiles different and, if they are, have you checked `Category Group Visibility Settings` to see that they have access to any?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves your are right the problem in if condition but this works when i change the language of the user. Yes the profile is same and have same permission set  for the both users.

Comment: What does the debug statement show for `category.getLabel()` and for `CategoryLabel` for the user with the language change when it doesn't work ?

Comment: @kris the issue is only happening in prod, not in dev. So I can't add debug over their. In dev everything is working fine.

Comment: Does dev have the same knowledge data category setup as prod?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves yes its same. As i said the problem is when i change he user language it is working when the language of the user is reverted back to old its stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have translations in your production and UAT org whereas in dev you do not. If you go to

Setup --> Translate

You can select Language (ex. Italian) and then `Data Category`.

[image]

Here you should see `Data Category Translation` for a given category. It's this value that is returning when you change the user's language in your call to `describeDataCategoryGroupStructures` and `getLabel()`. This doesn't match the value in the user field you're storing and checking against.

I'd recommend using the API value of the Data Category (`getName()`) as this does not suffer from the same situation.

In terms of documentation, it's not called out directly - but, [describeDataCategoryGroupStructures](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_calls_describedatacategorygroupstructures_describedatacategorygroupstructureresults.htm) does mention this bit about using `getLabel()`

> The label for the data category group in the Salesforce user
> interface.

Key being **Salesforce user interface**. This ends up being the **translated value**.

I was able to quickly test that in my own dev org after adding translations to the given data categories. The translated value was returned in `getLabel()` once one existed.

Comment: is it possible to get the actual value in the describeDataCategoryGroupStructures instead of translated value of the user. As per the doc it only have getlabel method which gives us the label value and it contain the translated value for the particular user.

Comment: The doc has all the listed things, so doesn't appear so. Any reason `getName()` won't work? Is CC_CaseRole__c a picklist? If it was, you could make the API name of the picklist values reflect the "name" instead of label. If it's text, you could consider making it a picklist to be able to control the values. If it must be text, you might have to resort to some sort of custom metadata to map name to label.

Comment: Yes the CC_CaseRole__c is picklist and we can add translation to it. But the problem is the same field is used in couple of places for the different logic. If we change it. It will impact the currently running logic. That is the reason I was trying to find a solution using describeDataCategoryGroupStructures.